# Individually place menu items

Tags: theming, routes

How can I position each menu item individually in Drupal 7?
I've created a quick visualisation how I want it to look like:

[image: Menu Visualisation]

The problem is that I still want to have hover effects and highlight the page I'm currently on.
The menu don't need to be dynamic because the menu items won't change.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`theme_links`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_links/7)

Like

```
<?php      
print theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links('menu-site-menu'),
'attributes' => array('class'=> array('links', 'site-menu')) ));
?>
```

Comment: I have NO idea how that would help me.. but I'm not good in PHP ;). I ended up building this exact menu with Dreamweaver and just adding it to page.tpl.php .